# Implementing Iterator on DoublyLinkedList

Tags: java, iterator

This question has been asked a few times but most were different or ArrayLists. Here is somewhat working. It's failing by a recursion call at the Iterator iterate() part but I don't know how this should be done.

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class KWLinkedList<E> extends AbstractSequentialList<E> {
    // Data Fields

    /** A reference to the head of the list. */
    private Node<E> head = null;
    /** A reference to the end of the list. */
    private Node<E> tail = null;
    /** The size of the list. */
    private int size = 0;
    /** Next node link.  */
    private Node<E> nextNode = null;
    private static KWLinkedList myList = new KWLinkedList();

    //Methods
    // Insert solution to programming exercise 4, section 8, chapter 2 here

    public void addFirst(E obj){
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(obj);
            tail = head;
            tail.next = head;
            size++;
        } else {
            head.prev = new Node(obj);
            tail.next = head;
            size++;
        }
    }

    public Node<E> getFirst(){
        if ( head == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("\n ERROR: List Is Empty! \n");
        }
        else {
            return head;
        }
    }

    public void addLast(E obj){
        if (head == null){
            addFirst(obj);
        } else {

        }
    }

    public Node<E> getLast(){
        if (head == null){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("\n ERROR: List Is Empty! \n");
        }
        return tail;
    }

    // Insert solution to programming exercise 3, section 8, chapter 2 here

    // Return ListIterator that begins just before the first list element.
    You can probably tell this was homework, why a teacher is making us write the whole iterator instead of using them in some effective way is not my idea of training.  But there must be a reason. Anyway, that pretty much did do the trick, THANKS Thomas!  @Override
public Iterator<E> iterator(){
    Iterator<E> iter = new KWListIter(0);
    return iter;
}
 /////////////  CORRECTED PART !!! //////////////////////////////
// Return ListIterator that begins just before the position index.
@Override
public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index){
    ListIterator<E> iter = new KWListIter(0);
    return iter;
}

    /**
     * Add an item at the specified index.
     * @param index The index at which the object is to be
     *        inserted
     * @param obj The object to be inserted
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the index is out
     *         of range (i < 0 || i > size())
     */
    @Override
    public void add(int index, E obj) {
            KWListIter iterator = new KWListIter(index);
            iterator.add(obj);
    }


    /**
     * Get the element at position index.
     * @param index Position of item to be retrieved
     * @return The item at index
     */
    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        return listIterator(index).next();
    }

    /**
     * Return the size of the list
     * @return the size of the list
     */
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    // Inner Classes
    /**
     * A Node is the building block for a double-linked list.
     */
    private static class Node<E> {

        /** The data value. */
        private E data;
        /** The link to the next node. */
        private Node<E> next = null;
        /** The link to the previous node. */
        private Node<E> prev = null;

        /**
         * Construct a node with the given data value.
         * @param dataItem The data value
         */
        private Node(E dataItem) {
            data = dataItem;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return " Data: " + data;
        }
    } //end class Node

    /** Inner class to implement the ListIterator interface. */
    private class KWListIter implements ListIterator<E> {

        /** A reference to the next item. */
        private Node<E> nextItem;
        /** A reference to the last item returned. */
        private Node<E> lastItemReturned;
        /** The index of the current item. */
        private int index = 0;

        /**
         * Construct a KWListIter that will reference the ith item.
         * @param i The index of the item to be referenced
         */
        public KWListIter(int i) {
            // Validate i parameter.
            if (i < 0 || i > size) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                        "Invalid index " + i);
            }
            lastItemReturned = null; // No item returned yet.
            // Special case of last item.
            if (i == size) {
                index = size;
                nextItem = null;
            } else { // Start at the beginning
                nextItem = head;
                for (index = 0; index < i; index++) {
                    nextItem = nextItem.next;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Construct a KWListIter that is a copy of another KWListIter
         * @param other The other KWListIter
         */
        public KWListIter (KWListIter other) {
            KWListIter itr = new KWListIter(0);
            itr.index = other.index;
            itr.lastItemReturned = other.lastItemReturned;
            itr.nextItem = other.nextItem;
        }

        /**
         * Indicate whether movement forward is defined.
         * @return true if call to next will not throw an exception
         */
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nextItem != null;
        }

        /** Move the iterator forward and return the next item.
         @return The next item in the list
         @throws NoSuchElementException if there is no such object
         */
        @Override
        public E next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            lastItemReturned = nextItem;
            nextItem = nextItem.next;
            index++;
            return lastItemReturned.data;
        }

        /**
         * Indicate whether movement backward is defined.
         * @return true if call to previous will not throw an exception
         */
        @Override
        public boolean hasPrevious() {
            return (nextItem == null && size != 0)
                    || nextItem.prev != null;
        }

        /**
         * Return the index of the next item to be returned by next
         * @return the index of the next item to be returned by next
         */
        @Override
        public int nextIndex() {
            return index;
        }

        /**
         * Return the index of the next item to be returned by previous
         * @return the index of the next item to be returned by previous
         */
        @Override
        public int previousIndex() {
            return index - 1;
        }

        /**
         * Move the iterator backward and return the previous item.
         * @return The previous item in the list
         * @throws NoSuchElementException if there is no such object
         */
        @Override
        public E previous() {
            if (!hasPrevious()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            if (nextItem == null) { // Iterator past the last element
                nextItem = tail;
            } else {
                nextItem = nextItem.prev;
            }
            lastItemReturned = nextItem;
            index--;
            return lastItemReturned.data;
        }

        /**
         * Add a new item between the item that will be returned
         * by next and the item that will be returned by previous.
         * If previous is called after add, the element added is
         * returned.
         * @param obj The item to be inserted
         */
        @Override
        public void add(E obj) {
            if (head == null) { // Add to an empty list.
                head = new Node<E>(obj);
                tail = head;
            } else if (nextItem == head) { // Insert at head.
                // Create a new node.
                Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(obj);
                // Link it to the nextItem.
                newNode.next = nextItem; // Step 1
                // Link nextItem to the new node.
                nextItem.prev = newNode; // Step 2
                // The new node is now the head.
                head = newNode; // Step 3
            } else if (nextItem == null) { // Insert at tail.
                // Create a new node.
                Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(obj);
                // Link the tail to the new node.
                tail.next = newNode; // Step 1
                // Link the new node to the tail.
                newNode.prev = tail; // Step 2
                // The new node is the new tail.
                tail = newNode; // Step 3
            } else { // Insert into the middle.
                // Create a new node.
                Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(obj);
                // Link it to nextItem.prev.
                newNode.prev = nextItem.prev; // Step 1
                nextItem.prev.next = newNode; // Step 2
                // Link it to the nextItem.
                newNode.next = nextItem; // Step 3
                nextItem.prev = newNode; // Step 4
            }
            // Increase size and index and set lastItemReturned.
            size++;
            index++;
            lastItemReturned = null;
        } // End of method add.

    // Insert solution to programming exercise 1, section 8, chapter 2 here

        @Override
        public void remove(){
            if (lastItemReturned == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
            else if ( lastItemReturned.prev == null){
                head = head.next;
                lastItemReturned = head;
            }
            else if (lastItemReturned.next == null){
                lastItemReturned.prev.next = null;
                lastItemReturned = null;
            }
            else {
                lastItemReturned.prev.next = lastItemReturned.next;
                lastItemReturned.next.prev = lastItemReturned.prev;
                lastItemReturned = lastItemReturned.next;
            }
            size--;
            index--;
            lastItemReturned = null;
        }

    // Insert solution to programming exercise 2, section 8, chapter 2 here

        @Override
        public void set(E newData){
            if (lastItemReturned == null && head != null){
                Node<E> temp = head;
                while (temp.next != null) {
                    temp = temp.next;
                }
                temp.next = new Node<E> (newData);
            }
            else if ( head == null || lastItemReturned.prev == null){
                KWLinkedList.this.addFirst(newData);
            }
            else {
                Node<E> temp = new Node<E>(newData);
                lastItemReturned.prev.next = temp;
                lastItemReturned.prev = temp;
            }
        }
    } //end class KWListIter

    // Insert solution to programming exercise 1, section 7, chapter 2 here
    public int indexOf(KWLinkedList list, E target){
        ListIterator<E> myIter = list.listIterator();
        while (myIter.hasNext()) {
            if(target.equals(myIter.next())) {
                break;
            }
        }
            return indexOf(myIter);
    }

    // Insert solution to programming exercise 2, section 7, chapter 2 here
    public int lastIndexOf(KWLinkedList list, ListIterator<E> target){
        ListIterator<E> myIter = list.listIterator();
        int hold = -1;
        while (myIter.hasNext()) {
            if(target.equals(myIter.next())) {
                hold = indexOf(myIter);
           }
        }
        return hold;
    }
    // Insert solution to programming exercise 3, section 7, chapter 2 here
    public ArrayList<Integer> indexOfMin(KWLinkedList list, ListIterator   target){
        ListIterator<E> myIter = list.listIterator();
        ArrayList<Integer> indexArray = new ArrayList<>();
        while (myIter.hasNext()) {
            if(target.equals(myIter.next())) {
                indexArray.add(indexOf(myIter));
            }
        }
        return indexArray;
    }

// Insert solution to programming exercise 1, section 6, chapter 2 here
    // 1.a.
    public void chapter2Sec6Exer1a(KWLinkedList linkedList){
        String bill = "Bill";

        linkedList.addFirst(bill);
    }
    //1.b.
    public void chapter2Sec6Exer1b(KWLinkedList linkedList){
        String sam = "Sam";
        String sue = "Sue";

        int holdIndex = linkedList.indexOf(linkedList, sam);
        linkedList.add(holdIndex, sue);
    }
    //1.c.
    public void chapter2Sec6Exer1c (KWLinkedList linkedList){
        linkedList.remove("Bill");
    }
    //1d.
    public void chapter2Sec6Exer1d (KWLinkedList linkedList){
       String sam = "Sam";
       boolean check = false;

       check = linkedList.remove(sam);
       if (check){
           System.out.println( sam + " was removed from list.");
       }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){

        myList.add("Tom");
        myList.add("Dick");
        myList.add("Harry");
        myList.add("Sam");

        displayList(myList);
    }

    public static void displayList(KWLinkedList myList){
        Iterator i = myList.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(i.next());
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: How exactly is it failing? Is there an exception?

Comment: It fails because to return an iterator you just call the `iterator()` method again. Instead you should create a `new KWListIter()` instance and return that.

Comment: No exception, it's just gets stuck in that recursion.

Comment: You can probably tell this was homework, why a teacher is making us write the whole iterator instead of using them in some effective way is not my idea of training.  But there must be a reason.

Comment: You can probably tell this was homework, why a teacher is making us write the whole iterator instead of using them in some effective way is not my idea of training.  But there must be a reason. Anyway, that pretty much did do the trick, THANKS Thomas!  
    public Iterator<E> iterator(){
        Iterator<E> iter = new KWListIter(0);
        return iter;
    }

    // Return ListIterator that begins just before the position index.
    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index){
        ListIterator<E> iter = new KWListIter(0);
        return iter;
    }